# How to write code that allow users to navigate through house schemes using map

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I want to build a mobile app that is about selling houses. I want to add a feature on my app that allow users to navigate through a scheme on the map that lead them to view houses indoor picture, here is a short video on this feature

https://www.youtube.com/shorts/zgKN9kYr_vM

how to write such code ?
Is it possible to write it using react native framework?

Comment: It is totally possible, but I'd recommend understanding the concepts of react native before diving in the code.

Comment: SO is not a place where you ask for an app and we create it for you.

Comment: @WrichikBasu I didn't ask you to create an app for me, I am asking about the possibility of coding such functionality using react native framework only, because some functionalities requires advanced graphics which means it has to be built with unity3D.